# property accessors for List<T>, and entity framework 6 linq queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to have a (EF6) Linq select statement instantiate a class, such that a property's `set` accessor is triggered with the values returned from the Linq statement?

I have tried code (similar) to that below, but despite the query returning data, the `set`'s `value` is an empty list. I am assuming that Linq creates a new instance of MyModel, and then adds the records from the record set.

Is it possible to trigger `doSomething()` **after** MyList is fully populated, but from within the scope of MyModel (i.e. not adding a subsequent call after `context.SomeEntities.Select(...)`)?

```
public class MyModel{
  private List<string> _myList;
  public List<string> MyList {
    get { return _myList; } 
    set { _myList = value; doSomething(); }
  }
  private void doSomething() {...}
}

.. 
context.SomeEntities.Select(x => new MyModel { MyList = x.YourList });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is "Yes." The following worked for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        List<MyModel> myModelsList = context.Products.Include("Names").AsEnumerable().Select(x =>
        {
            MyModel model = new MyModel();
            model.MyList = x.Names.Select(pn => pn.Name).ToList();
            return model;
        }).ToList();
    }

    static void CreateAndSeedDatabase()
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        Product product1 = new Product() { Names = new List<ProductName> { new ProductName { Name = "1" } } };
        Product product2 = new Product() { Names = new List<ProductName> { new ProductName { Name = "2" } } };
        context.Products.Add(product1);
        context.Products.Add(product2);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductName> ProductNames { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductName> Names { get; set; }
}

public class ProductName
{
    public int ProductNameId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
    private List<string> _myList;
    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set { _myList = value; doSomething(); }
    }
    private void doSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_myList[0]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think that works with Entity Framework as Select takes an Expression<Func<>> and not a Func<>.     `CS0834 A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

Comment: You are correct. I added the AsEnumerable method prior to the select statement to avoid the error you mention above.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful for me!